# How to get a specific upper class of $(this) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have the following html.

```
<div class="new-row>
   <img class="trash" src = "trash.png">
   <img class="trash" src = "trash.png">
</div>
<div class="new-row>
    <img class="trash" src = "trash.png">
    <img class="trash" src = "trash.png">
</div>
```

Also I have the following jquery code

```
$(".trash").on("click",trashClicked);
```

How can I get the number of (".trash") in each new-row class. I don't want to get the total number of img tags with class trash. I want to get the specific number of img tags with class trash when a trash image is clicked in specific new -row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `trashClicked`, `this` will refer to the specific `img` that was clicked. You can then work from there to figure out how many `.trash` `img`s there are in that row:

1. Your `img` elements are siblings of one another, so you could use [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

   ```
   var count = $(this).siblings().length + 1; // + 1 for the one we're calling it on
   ```
2. A more general solution would use [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the enclosing `.new-row`, and then [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all of the `.trash` elements, even if they're at different levels.

   ```
   var count = $(this).closest(".new-row").find(".trash).length;
   ```

---

It's **well worth** your time to read through the jQuery API, beginning to end. It doesn't take long, and it repays the time you spend doing it almost immediately.